# (FORTRAN 90) I/O read/print

Tags: fortran

I have a .dat file that has 2 columns, and values listed under the columns. However, there is random spacing between entries. Both columns are the same length (just random blank lines in the data).

I need to be able to read these and then display them.

THANK YOU! for any suggestions/help
Joe

I've tried simply using just OPEN but just get an I/O error.

```
PROGRAM TEST1


OPEN( 2, FILE='grades.dat', ACCESS='DIRECT', FORM='FORMATTED')

READ( 2) X, Y 


END PROGRAM TEST1
```

Comment: Please show what have you done

Comment: @BBdev           
Thank you for the reply. I've tried about 10 different iterations but basically they all look similar to this with OPEN/PRINT or READ. I just need to get all the values from the file.

Comment: You didn't have a format specified in your READ command. READ(2,*) X,Y should fix it. Also, it is good manners to close a file after reading it and to close questions that are solved. <3

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the file, line by line, into a character string.  If the string is non-blank, corresponding to a line containing the two numbers rather than being blank, it reads them into the next array element.  It is assumed that the arrays have been declared large enough. Does this answer your question?  A better design would read the file to determine the number of numbers, rewind the file, and allocate the arrays to the correct size, then read the file into the arrays.

EDIT: actually, Fortran will automatically skip blank lines, so the solution can be simpler:

```
program read_file

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

implicit none

integer :: i, j, ReadCode
real, dimension (100) :: x, y

open (unit=2, file="grades.dat", access="sequential", form="formatted", status="old", action="read" )

i = 1
ReadLoop: do

  read (2, *, iostat=ReadCode )   x (i), y (i)

   if ( ReadCode /= 0 ) then
      if ( ReadCode == iostat_end ) then
         exit ReadLoop
      else
         write ( *, '( / "Bad read: ", I0 )' )  ReadCode
         stop
      end if
   end if

   i = i + 1

end do ReadLoop

do j=1,i-1
   write (*, *) x(j), y(j)
end do

end program read_file
```

Comment: I just tried to run this exact code and got: 

run-time error F605: WRITE(CON)
- A edit descriptor expected for CHARACTER

Comment: I'm very, very new to fortran. I haven't read how to impliment arrays yet. But this code looks pretty close.